# where in the FHS does command less store its buffers?

Tags: storage, less, kubuntu

Using Kubuntu 20.04, which is running from an USB stick. Therefore there is a `/cow` overlay file system mounted on `/`. The USB stick has a total capacity of 32 GB, But to the `cow` overlay file system only 16 GB were assigned. My computer has a RAM size of 32 GB (as shown by utility "free" in total).

The cause of my current state is, that I have forgotten to disable the internet connection.

Before, I have used aptitude to search, but I have not intentionally downloaded something. Overnight from the 16 GB in "cow" about 2 GB have gone used. `df -Th -a` shows "used" is grown from 21% to 33%.

Now I am investigating, who has done what.

For this I have running (for many hours) a self-written program `wels_fullpath` (based on bash globstar and `**`) over `/`, piping the output to `sort` (for sorting by time), and from sort to `less`.
While this is running, I have to pay attention which memory is used for buffers of `sort` and of `less`. (I am neglecting sort in the moment).

For this I have continuously running the `watch` utility to observe the changes in `df` and `free`:

```
watch -d  "df -T -a >/tmp/WEx_df__2; diff -U0 /tmp/WEx_df__1 /tmp/WEx_df__2; free -w -h"
```

`strace` shows that `wels_fullpath` is working.

But neither in `df` nor in `free` are changes reported.

So the question came up, where in the list of `df` some continuously growing buffers should appear?

I have read the documentation to `less` and I have long googled in internet. There are some good articles regarding less and buffers. But nowhere is a description where in the FHS the less buffers should be seen and with what a name.

- addendum:

A new question came up.

I have changed my calling sequence and do no longer use "less" here.

Nevertheless my question is of general importance for me.

And perhaps for the place where the buffers of less are, I have not written the appropriate term "storage". I have ment "in memory or on disk". less buffers should have an effect on either "free" or "df". And this should be noted in some documentatin.

Now my command chain is:

/.../wels_fullpath -d / 2>/dev/null | grep -v -e "^fd1" | sort -s -r -k7,8 >/tmp/WEx01

As I see in "top" ("htop" is not installed by default) the execution is yet on the very beginning:

top -p <PID>

shows:

PID      USER  PR  NI  VIRT   RES

2159985  root  20  0  242132  235816

SHR   S  %CPU  %MEM  TIME+

3160  R  99.3  0.7  1634:33

COMMAND

wels_fullpath

In my program I use an array. And while reading the files in the source "/", they are written into the array. Thus VIRT and RES are continuously growing, ok.

But my perpetually running "watch" of "df" and "free" does not show these changes. The values in "free" varies by a very small amount up and down.

Thus my additional question is, please:

why the growing memory usage of my program is not reflected in "free"?

is there an utility in Linux, Kubuntu to analize and display  a l l  aspects of memory (like "df", "du")?

Regards
antondhidh

Oh, excuse me. I have remembered and have found:

/proc/meminfo gives a good overview.
pmap gives memory usage per process.

Sorry having bothered you.

Regards
antondhidh

Comment: "I am neglecting sort in the moment." - You probably shouldn't. Unlike `less`, `sort` may indeed create temporary files on disk if the input becomes too big to sort in memory.

Answer (score 4):

`less` doesn’t store buffers anywhere in the file system. Its buffers, configurable using the `--buffers` and `--auto-buffers` options, are kept in memory (potentially in swap).